# no reference to pthread_mutex_lock with -lpthread compiled

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am compiling a program that contains mutex semaphores from the pthread library but when i compile using the -lpthread flag I am getting an undefined reference error.

```
gcc -lpthread prodcon.c
/tmp/ccESOlOn.o: In function `producer':
prodcon.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `pthead_mutex_lock'
prodcon.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `pthead_mutex_unlock'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The syntax for the mutex lock is like so:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
```

is a global declaration so that it can be used by multiple threads. within the functions I am calling the mutex like so:

```
pthead_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
pthead_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

But i am getting the compiler error, I also tried compiling with the -pthread flag

```
gcc -pthread prodcon.c
/tmp/cc6wiQPR.o: In function `producer':
prodcon.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `pthead_mutex_lock'
prodcon.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `pthead_mutex_unlock'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have searched for answers but am at a loss and would appreciate any help with figuring out why it has an undefined reference when I am linking in the library that contains the mutex locks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order matters, so use:

```
gcc prodcon.c -lpthread
```

Or better:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread prodcon.c -lpthread
```

---

Are you sure you use `pthead_mutex_lock`? Or is this a typo? Anyways it should be `pthread_mutex_lock`. Same for `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Comment: it was a typo, but compiling like that seems to have done it though I am sure I tried that I must have made an error somewhere. Thanks!